# what properties can be added to a QR code to make it copy proof?

Tags: security, qr-code

If we want to provide more security to the consumer for authenticating their product and by using QR code scans, what techniques we can used for making that QR code copy proof and non-duplicate?

Comment: A QR-code is a visual pattern; an image you can scan e.g. with your phone. What exactly do you mean when you say you want to make it "copy proof"? What is to stop anyone from taking a picture of it, and reproducing it, for example?

Comment: I mean to say that, is there anything or any technology can we insert into the QR code label so that we can stop counterfeiter from reproducing it or else it will result into non-authenticate/duplicate when counterfeiter tries to copy it or reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider the  digital image of the QR Code before printing. You can add a secure graphic or copy detection pattern (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_graphic)  into the QR Code (pay attention to the error-correction level of the QR Code versus the space you use).  Once printed, the secure graphic will  irreversibly loose information, and if someone tries to make a copy of it, there will be an additional information loss. As the secure graphic will a lower amount of information in the copy than in  an original print, you can use that that to discriminate originals from counterfeits. An app is needed to analyse the image of the secure graphic in real-time when you scan the QR Code. See example of this is done with [Scantrust](https://www.scantrust.com), and there is a [developer portal](https://devportal.scantrust.com/) to support you in integrating in your app.

Note that there are other techniques based on digital watermarking, but they are easier to hack given that digital watermarks need to respect an imperceptibility constraint and the usable signal is much weaker.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer: Think of a QR code as a compressed block of plain text. You can sign it for non purposes of authenticity and non-repudiation, or encrypt it for secrecy, but you can't magically stop it from being copied and reproduced as a whole.**

**Longer answer:**
I think what you are asking is whether it is possible to add some kind of *identification* or *signature* to a QR-code? If so, then the answer is yes - you can put pretty much whatever you like in there, so long as you keep it within the [storage limits for the input mode you are using (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Storage).

This means you could for instance add a digital signature to it, if you wanted to.

**Example:**
Say you wanted to encode the text "*Public Message*" into a QR-code, and leave it for someone to read. To prove that the message is really from you, you could use PKI and sign it with your secret key - that is, append an encrypted version of "*Public Message*" to the text. Decryption of that last part will then only be possible using your public key, and doing so will prove that it was encrypted using your private key, which indicates that the message must have come from you (or someone with access to your private key).

Now if someone tried to copy your QR code, and change it's message to the slightly more kinky "*Public M**a**ssage*" instead, a recipient could check the attached signature and see that there is a mismatch, and so conclude that the code is invalid (i.e. has been manipulated).

If a message has a *valid* signature, this will prove that you are the author, and that the message has not been manipulated. You still won't be able to stop anyone from *copying* the code and reproducing it as a whole though.

**Alternative: Encryption using a public key?**
If you wanted to post a secret message intended for a specific recipient, you could encrypt it using that person's public key. In that case you could share the QR-code freely, and only the recipient would be able to read it's contents; anyone else would just see garbled text.

**Alternative 2: One-Time Pass (OTP)?**
If you want to make sure a QR-code is used only once, you could have it include a unique ID, and implement server side logic that accepts that code, checks it's validity, and invalidates it after a single use. You can also limit the time for which such a QR-Code is valid. This is how [website logins using QR-codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Website_login) work.